# MVC3 Authorization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

There is a credential system I'm developing. No MembershipProvider applied for this purpose.
I have designed and developed my own custom Role Management System.

My question is, how can I `add [Authorize(Role="Super User")]` dynamically?
I mean, for example, I defined a new user User4 who have access to Action4, attribute above the action is, for example, `[Authorize("Super User,"Admin")]` Now I want to make Action4 accessible for User4. This is not mentioned already. How can I handle this dynamically without adding new user authorization attribute each time for different Actions???

I thanks in advance for any suggestion and sample code.